# UIBarButtonItemに使えるアイコンについて

Tags: swift, xcode6, ios8, storyboard

xcode6.2で開発しています。
storyboadを使っていますが、swiftでも方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

UIBarButtonItemに

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html
に載ってる３６個のアイコン（下図）
[image: ３６個のアイコン]

を指定したいのですが、これはあくまで説明用のサンプルなのでしょうか？

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/UIBarButtonSystemItem
に

```
enum UIBarButtonSystemItem : Int {
    case Done
    case Cancel
    case Edit
    case Save
    case Add
    case FlexibleSpace
    case FixedSpace
    case Compose
    case Reply
    case Action
    case Organize
    case Bookmarks
    case Search
    case Refresh
    case Stop
    case Camera
    case Trash
    case Play
    case Pause
    case Rewind
    case FastForward
    case Undo
    case Redo
    case PageCurl
}
```

と記載されており、これが、storyboardのBar Button ItemのAttributes InspectorのIdentifierで選択できるリストに対応してそうなので、これ以外をアイコンのように表示させる場合は画像を別途用意しなければいけないという理解であっていますか？

Answer (score 1):

はい。
Apple製のアプリでよく使われているアイコンはUIBarButtonSystemItemを指定して、自由に使うことができます。それ以外のアイコンが使いたい場合、自分で用意する必要があります

Comment: 分かりました。アイコン集を探して使用しようと思います。